# implementing list : adding a node at the end

Tags: c++, list

```
//function to insert at the end of the list
 nodLista* inserareSfarsit(nodLista* capat,Produs p)
{
nodLista* nou= creareNod(p);
if(capat==NULL)
    {
    capat=nou;
    return nou;
    }


    nodLista* temp=capat;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
        temp=temp->next;
        temp->next=nou;
        return capat;
        }
}    

void main(){
nodLista* capatLista=NULL;
Produs p,p1,p2,p3,p4;
p1=generator("lapte",2);
p= generator("cafea",20);
p2=generator("seminte",10);
p3=generator("sticle",3);
p4=generator("pahare",4);
//afisareProdus(p);
afisareLista(capatLista);
capatLista=inserareInceput(capatLista,creareNod(p1));
//afisareLista(capatLista);
capatLista=inserareInceput(capatLista,creareNod(p2));
capatLista=inserareInceput(capatLista,creareNod(p3));
capatLista=inserareSfarsit(capatLista,p4);
afisareLista(capatLista);

_getch();
}
```

so now my list should look like this:

```
sticle 3
seminte 10
lapte 2
```

but when i add the p4 product at the end it looks like this:

```
sticle
seminte
pahare
```

so the product lapte has dissapeared

// inserareInceput  insert a node at the begining of the list

// afisareLista: displays the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move those two lines out of the loop, and you are done:

```
temp->next=nou;
return capat;
```